# How to display mongoDB collection in html?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a beginner with mongoose and would like to display a mongoDB document(s) from "exColl" collection in a file called "example.ejs" in a basic html list however I have hit various problems. There are other posts on this topic yet I remain stumped by this.

-I do have a working chunk of code that outputs all documents from exColl.find({}) using res.json, obviously putting them in json format. However I have been unable to adapt this code into something that works using res.render for example.

-When I define a variable in app.js and try to access it in example.ejs the variable is not found, therefore even if I could save the results of exColl.find({}) in a variable I don't see how I would be able to enter it into the HTML

Clearly I don't know what I don't know which is very frustrating. If someone could help fill my conceptual gaps that would be fantastic.

---Edit----
Adding a snippet I have tried

```
app.get("/example", function (req, res){
    exColl.find({})
    .exec(function (err, examples){
        if (err) {
            res.send("an error has occurred")
        } else res.render(examples: examples);
        });
    });
```

In .ejs file

```
<p> <%= examples %> </p>
```

Comment: How are you trying to render this?  Using Pug/Jade/some other template engine?

Comment: My view engine is ejs

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `res.render()`?  Post as much pertinent code from the route handler as you can as well as pertinent code from the `ejs` file.

Comment: @zero298 edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the EJS syntax which you should review here: [EJS Docs](http://ejs.co/#docs).  Consider the following test project structure:

```
.
├── index.js
├── package.json
├── setup.js
└── views
    ├── index.ejs
    └── table.ejs
```

I create a test DB with **setup.js** so that we have some dummy posts to display:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:8081/test", {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", {
    title:String,
    body: String
});

const toMake = [
    {title: "hello", body: "world"},
    {title: "foo", body: "bar"},
    {title: "fizz", body: "buzz"},
    {title: "a", body: "b"}
];

Post.insertMany(toMake)
    .then(()=>{
        console.log("done");
        mongoose.connection.close();
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I create an EJS template **views/table.ejs** to render my posts as a table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Body</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% posts.forEach(post => { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= post.title %></td>
                <td><%= post.body %></td>
            </tr>
        <% }) %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I then create an EJS template **views/index.ejs** to use the table template

```
<main>
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    <%- include("table", {posts}); %>
</main>
```

I also make a server to respond to requests in **index.js** and run it with `node index.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:8081/test", {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});

const app = express();

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", {
    title: String,
    body: String
});

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const posts = await Post.find({});
    res.render("index", {posts});
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening"));
```

And when I `curl localhost:3000` I get the rendered HTML:

```
<main>
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Body</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>hello</td>
                    <td>world</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>foo</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>fizz</td>
                    <td>buzz</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>a</td>
                    <td>b</td>
                </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</main>
```

---

No matter what, I will need to feed data to the `res.render()` function and populate the render scope with all the data needed to render.

However, I have made **table.ejs** reusable.  So lets say that I have another page that I want to be able to show some of the posts in a tabular fashion.

I have another EJS template: **views/profile.ejs** that looks like this:

```
<main>
    <h1>2 Posts</h1>
    <%- include("table", {posts: posts.slice(0, 2)}); %>
</main>
```

And I add another route to my application at `/sliced`:

```
app.get("/sliced", async (req, res) => {
    const posts = await Post.find({});
    res.render("profile", {posts});
});
```

Whenever I curl `localhost:3000/sliced` I get only the first 2 items in the posts since I only populated the `include`'s scope with a slice of all the posts:

```
<main>
    <h1>2 Posts</h1>
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Body</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>hello</td>
                <td>world</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>foo</td>
                <td>bar</td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

</main>
```

Comment: Thank you @zero298, this code works! As well as the .esj problem I was misusing schemas, I think. How would I be able to place this table in a page other than home without disturbing the get method?

Comment: @HenryPopiolek Make another EJS template for the table only and use `<%- include("views/table", {tableData}); %>`  Do note though that you will still need to provide `tableData` into the render scope just as has been done in my answer example.  The linked docs also cover using `<%include%>`

Comment: @HenryPopiolek Please see my edited answer for a little bit more detail.