# How to convert nodejs-mongodb application's get json response into table

Tags: node.js

[expected output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtmAy.png)   I'm using node.js,express ,mongodb as database.I'm trying to convert my get api response into table format.My get api response is:-

[
{
name: "***",
email: "vs1111.sw@gamil.com",
address: "***",
date: "12-jan-19",
starting_time: "12:45",
ending_time: "2:00"
},
{
name: "******",
email: "vs11111.sw@gmail.com",
address: "*****",
date: "12-jan-19",
starting_time: "12:45",
ending_time: "2:00"
}
]

I tried my multiple way like html-pdf,json-to-table modules.But   don't get proper table format.Please put your valuable comments.Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/populate-json-data-to-html-table-using-javascript.htm

Comment: What format exactly you want to represent above data. A JSON can always be represented in a tabular form unless it is multiple nested. Can you give a sample of what you want?

Comment: You're practically asking the same question as this: [How to display mongoDB collection in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52262414/691711) except you have no code to show.  Please add how you have tried to use html-pdj, json-to-table, etc. Please add how you have used them in code, and in your question, and explain ***exactly*** how it didn't work "don't get proper table format" is not an adequate description.

Comment: Thank you zero298, I apply your suggested blog. ** But I'm getting this Error **     Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%=".
    at /home/john/Desktop/nodejs/cab-application/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:693:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Template.generateSource (/home/john/Desktop/nodejs/cab-application/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:678:15)
    at Template.compile (/home/john/Desktop/nodejs/cab-application/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:557:12)
    at Object.compile (/home/john/Desktop/nodejs/cab-application/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:389:16)